# Firebase method is returning an unknown Error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to send data to Cloud Storage using the Firebase SDK for iOS. In doing so I'm creating a reference (StorageReference) in this way:

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.CONFIG_ROOF_REF).child("Posts").child(videoIDString)
```

And using the putFile method:

```
storageRef.putFile(from: videoURL, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil{

                ProgressHUD.showError(error?.localizedDescription)
                              return
                      }
                          storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                              if error != nil {
                                  return
                              }else {
                                  self.videourl = url?.absoluteString
                                  onSuccess(videourl!)
                              }

            })
        }
```

I pass in the argument videoURL and I receive back the error:

```
An unknown error occurred, please check the server response
```

I cannot understand why I receive that error since the videoURL I'm passing seems legit.

The videoURL I'm passing is this one:

```
file:///Users/andreagualandris/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7D3329AC-AD8D-4553-AC61-FDF8435134B6/data/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/8229E521-A7A2-4C09-8312-CC6106C2FED8/tmp/trim.7CC60B3A-6982-4F42-AA63-ED094288A562.MOV
```

So I think this is a normal URL and there shouldn't be any problem with it.

The actual server response on the console is :

```
2020-01-26 10:31:27.107215+0100 InstagramClone[2517:235684] Task <4AC8F3F2-1CC6-4064-BBF7-6D0375769C9A>.<1> finished with error [-1] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1 "unknown error" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/instagramclone-1ed36.appspot.com/o/Posts%2F412BA396-6CAD-4197-817F-1AA0D9E6E6FE?uploadType=resumable&name=Posts%2F412BA396-6CAD-4197-817F-1AA0D9E6E6FE&upload_id=AEnB2UoAHEWQ0WDv_Id2TK_xSL_71Jrj8kbmuDfLpGkO8fBe6e9sBF74QUj5r0MLdltJN79z5fWAtoqOx8JSAfpppyPe6qKrxA&upload_protocol=resumable, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/instagramclone-1ed36.appspot.com/o/Posts%2F412BA396-6CAD-4197-817F-1AA0D9E6E6FE?uploadType=resumable&name=Posts%2F412BA396-6CAD-4197-817F-1AA0D9E6E6FE&upload_id=AEnB2UoAHEWQ0WDv_Id2TK_xSL_71Jrj8kbmuDfLpGkO8fBe6e9sBF74QUj5r0MLdltJN79z5fWAtoqOx8JSAfpppyPe6qKrxA&upload_protocol=resumable, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "BackgroundUploadTask <4AC8F3F2-1CC6-4064-BBF7-6D0375769C9A>.<1>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=BackgroundUploadTask <4AC8F3F2-1CC6-4064-BBF7-6D0375769C9A>.<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=unknown error}
```

Comment: Your question said "Firebase Realtime Database", but your code is working with Cloud Storage for Firebase.  So I edited it and changed the tags.

Comment: The URL in the error description results in a Bad Request - are you sure it is correct?

Comment: @koen yes it is correct I just added spaces to make it fit better, try now, it should work fine

Comment: @DougStevenson yes man, I'm sorry I meant Firebase Storage, my bad.

Comment: @bellaGU you changed the local URL, not the firebase URL in the error message.

Comment: @koen I updated It, now It should be fine. If the URL results in a bad request, what could be the reason why it's not working? Sorry but I'm not an expert in this field.

Comment: @bellaGU if I paste that new url in my browser, I now get "Invalid request.  X-Goog-Upload-Command header is missing." No idea what that means though, I don't use Firebase, but I'm sure it will point you in the right direction. And just a general note, there is a lot of info to be found in error messages :)